# Chart.js 3.x custom positioners: cannot use them in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, chart.js, chart.js3

I'm using `ChartJS v3` and I'm trying to implement a custom tooltip positioner, as described in the docs:

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/configuration/tooltip.html#position-modes

However, the problem is that I'm coding in `TypeScript` and the type checking is fighting me over this.
The first problem is that I cannot define the custom positioner like in the example:

```
const tooltipPlugin = Chart.registry.getPlugin('tooltip');
tooltipPlugin.positioners.myCustomPositioner = ...
```

because the type returned by `getPlugin()` does not contain the `positioners` property.

The second problem is when you then have to configure the plugin. I cannot do this:

```
plugins: {
    tooltip: {
      position: 'myCustomPositioner',
      ...
    }
}
```

because the `position` property only accepts the defaults built in values (`'average'` and `'nearest'`) but does not take a custom string.

How do I work around this? I wasa happy that the latest ChartJS provides strong types, but they are no use if the make core features of the library unusable... what am I missing?

Comment: are you using react/vue/angular or purely TS with webpack/babel?

Comment: @MicFung: I'm using Angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for escape complication error i just resolved by using 'as' operator.

```
tooltip:{
 position: 'myCustomPositioner' as 'average',
}
```

Comment: This is not the proper way to do this, please see my answer.

Answer (score 9):

The proper way to do this is to extend the positioners map typings to include your custom function.
Refer to https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.4.1/developers/charts.html, which includes how to extend the typings for custom charts, it is similar to this.

By just casting the position, as the solution from @bangash, you are tricking the compiler. That solution also does not solve the problem when you *create* the positioner.

**Note:** This expects you are using ChartJS 3.x

Create a file called `chartjs.d.ts` somewhere in your project that `tsconfig.json` reads from, for example `@types/chartjs.d.ts`

```js
import type { TooltipPositionerFunction } from 'chart.js';

declare module 'chart.js' {
  // Extend tooltip positioner map
  interface TooltipPositionerMap {
    cursor: TooltipPositionerFunction<ChartType>;
  }
}
```

Then, create your function where you are registering your components:

```js
import { Tooltip } from 'chart.js'

// Create positioner to put tooltip at cursor position
Tooltip.positioners.cursor = function (chartElements, coordinates) {
  return coordinates;
};
```

Now you can use your cursor as `position` property of the tooltip.